# Binding a title to selected combobox text

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, charts

How do I bind the title of my chart to the text selected in a `ComboBox`?

Here is my code:

`XAML`

```
<DVC:Chart.Axes>
    <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Title="Ammount of calls" ShowGridLines="True" Interval="auto"/>
    <DVC:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Title="{Binding Path=combobox1}" ShowGridLines="True" Interval="1"/>
</DVC:Chart.Axes>
```

As you can see there is the text I am trying to bind to the `ComboBox1` in the `x-axis`.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combobox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="combobox1_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Graph per Hour"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Graph per Minute"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Above is the ComboBox. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Title="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=combobox1}"
```

Comment: @Silentdarkness, do remember that although this works in your case, it may not give you desired results if Content of your ComboBoxItem is something other than a string. In that case, you will need to bind to the relevant part of the Content property. See example section at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx) for possible values of Content property.